# Boolean field: hide (in display) if unchecked

Tags: 7, entities

I have a content type with a boolean field (checkbox). Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is this:

- If this field is **checked**, only show the *label* (when viewing the page)
- If this field is **unchecked**, don't show the field *at all* (no label and no value)

Is there a simple way of doing this? (Without resorting to Views or custom code)

I've noticed that if I use "Check boxes/radio buttons" as widget type for this field, it comes close to what I want, since it offers three values to choose from (yes, no, and N/A), and if N/A is selected, the field isn't rendered on the display page.

However:

- I don't want 3 values to choose, but 2. (3 might be confusing for users, and having to explain *"Don't use the 'no' value"* really isn't a good solution.)
- I don't want the value to be displayed when "Yes" is selected (only the label).

Comment: *"Without resorting to Views or custom code"* - looks like a pretty harsh requirements. Almost all of templating **is custom code**.

Comment: The answer is a simple "no", there's no way to do that without 'resorting' to Views or custom code. Well, you might find a module that happens to provide that tiny bit of functionality as well as whatever else it does, but I doubt it

Comment: OK, thanks for your comments. I guess I'll use Views, then (I already use it anyway).

Comment: @Clive in case you're interested, it's actually possible using just core functionality. See my answer for more details.

Comment: @s427 I stand corrected :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, so it is possible and actually rather simple. Here's how I did it in the end:

Edit the field's settings:
"value if checked" -> use the text you want to see displayed when checked
"value if unchecked" -> leave empty

And then under Content type > Manage Display, **hide** the label for this field.

This way, only the value of this field will be shown.
Since the value when *unchecked* is empty, nothing will be shown when the field is not checked.

Comment: You still get the empty divs which can be disturbing for theming. I had to use hook_field_attach_view_alter and set #access to FALSE to get rid of the field-items / field-item divs

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, I think you just need to use a Boolean field and configure it as a **Single On/Off checkbox**.  Then in the field settings, choose **Use field label instead of the "On value" as label**.  I suspect the last part is the missing piece in your puzzle.

Otherwise, you may need the [Conditional Fields](https://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module:

> Conditional Fields allows you to manage sets of dependencies between
>   fields. When a field is “dependent”, it will only be available for
>   editing and displayed if the state of the “dependee” field matches the
>   right condition. When editing a node (or any other entity type that
>   supports fields, like users and categories), the dependent fields are
>   dynamically modified with the States API. You can, for example, define
>   a custom “Article teaser" field that is shown only if a "Has teaser"
>   checkbox is checked.

Comment: I did play with the `Use field label instead of the "On value" as label` setting, but as far as I can tell, it only applies to how the field is displayed when *editing* the content. It doesn't change the fact that the value is displayed when viewing the page, regardless of its state. I guess I'll just use Views.

Comment: @s427 I would play with it some more.  I was looking at a site I had worked on where I did something similar.  Unfortunately, the client is reviewing it, so I can't mess with the settings.

Comment: I'll look again, but frankly I think I've already tried all combinations.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to solve a very similar problem. While learning how to convert a legacy system to Drupal, I realized I had several tables in which a boolean field determines whether to hide or show several other fields. In addition to whether or not those other fields get shown, under no circumstances would I need to actually show either the label or the value of this actual boolean field.

After reading the other comments and suggestions and wrestling unsuccessfully with Conditional Fields, I found that the piece I was missing was [Display Suite](https://drupal.org/node/1795294), which seems to give you a lot more control over the placement, hiding, and arrangement of labels and fields. Since my particular use case is a little bit different from yours, I am not sure this will help you -- did you already try Display Suite (in concert with Views, of course)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. No I didn't know this module. However I think I can do what I need using just Views (if not, I'll check out Display Suite). My question was whether or not it was achievable using Drupal core modules only. Apparently it's not.